# What is the purpose of the two colons in this Python string-slicing statement?

Tags: python, slice

For example,

```
str = "hello"
str[1::3]
```

And where can I find this in Python documentation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explain slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-slice-notation)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

in [sequences' description](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#index-510):

```
s[i:j:k]    slice of s from i to j with step k
```

> The slice of `s` from `i` to `j` with step `k` is defined as the sequence of items with index `x = i + n*k` such that `0 <= n < (j-i)/k`. In other words, the indices are `i`, `i+k`, `i+2*k`, `i+3*k` and so on, stopping when `j` is reached (but never including `j`). If `i` or `j` is greater than `len(s)`, use `len(s`). **If `i` or `j` are omitted or `None`, they become “end” values (which end depends on the sign of `k`)**. Note, `k` cannot be zero. If `k` is `None`, it is treated like 1.